# Change QLabel Text in PyQT

Tags: python, qt, text, label, qlabel

im new at Python and QT. Here is my Code Snipped.

```
form_class = uic.loadUiType("mainWindow.ui")[0]  # Load the UI

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.loginFPBut.clicked.connect(lambda: self.loginFP)

    def loginFP(self):
        self.labelSensorStatus.setText('Button pressed') 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

How can i change the Text from Label called "labelSensorStatus"?

Comment: I don't see `labelSensorStatus` in your code. Do you have it in `.ui` file ?

Comment: in my .ui file it appears as a normal Qlabel Object. In my Code you can see it in function "loginFP", which is called by pressing a Button called "loginFPBut".

Comment: Removing the "**lambda:**" tag in your connection and using `        self.loginFPBut.clicked.connect(self.loginFP)` the code seems fine and works.

Comment: Now i get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 68, in <module>
    myWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
  File "start.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.loginFPBut.clicked.connect(self.loginFP)
TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'QWidget'`